# Content Security Policy vs variable inline style (CSP vs CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, security, inline-styles

Quite simply, I could add the directive `unsafe-inline` and be done with it, but I'm scratching my head at how it could possibly be done otherwise to control variable data such as positioning of an element by the pixel.

In short, I've eliminated everything inline except for one thing, a transform which is used to pan and zoom an image:

```
document.getElementById("img")
 .setAttribute("style","transform:translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) scale("+z+")");
```

This is necessary functionality, but I can't imagine what can be done to replace other than creating an insane number of CSS definitions for every pixel position possible and every zoom value possible. That obviously would be a train wreck.

My current solution is to just relax the CSP on this specific page and allow inline styles, since it is behind a 2FA log in access, so not something that a hacker would naturally be able to access. All the data displayed is added by logged in users as well, so that limits the possibility of a XSS payload.

Comment: What if you don't use `setAttribute` and just use the HTML DOM's `style` property directly, instead?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: I think you are missing what CSP entails. It demands that *all* inline styles be removed, so using the `style` attribute is not acceptable.

Comment: no not really, there's a difference between `setAttribute` and direct DOM manipulation.  I just tested on a website I know has such a CSP, and in the console I can use `document.body.style.background = "blue"` but `document.body.setAttribute("style", "background:blue")` violates the CSP.

Comment: Good question, by the way!  I recently went through all this pain.  I'm sure CSP questions will be more popular very soon.

Comment: That's still an inline style, regardless of how you represent it. Just because you are getting away with it now doesn't mean that you will when CSP Level 3 is adopted.

Comment: That's the whole point, the styles are not inline, inline means in the HTML element's attribute values, where injection can occur. DOM property manipulation is governed by script rules in CSP. They're different APIs that control the styling of an element. Manipulating attributes is slower too and also not encouraged for that reason. CSP doesn't exist to prevent styling elements directly, it exists to prevent unwanted code injection.

Comment: You do have something on the attribute vs property, I hadn't considered that previously.

Answer (score 2):

There is much discussion about this here: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/212

Which is succinctly summarised towards the end:

> CSP is checked at parsing and blocks parsing the style attribute. Any direct operations go through.

Using `setAttribute` invokes the HTML parser and CSP is triggered.

So, instead of:

```
.setAttribute("style","transform:translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) scale("+z+")");
```

You would need:

```
.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) scale("+z+")";
```

It may sound odd that one method works and the other does not, I think the understanding here is that there is a subtle difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties. https://joji.me/en-us/blog/html-attribute-vs-dom-property/

Comment: After some scant reading on the subject (busy at the moment), this looks to be correct. I went nuclear and cleared all styles and replaced with CSS rule-sets, including all uses of  `obj.style.display = "none"` with `obj.className = "hide"`.

I was reading on CSP Level 3, and it made it seem that any use of "style" was to be shunned. I will get back to this answer once I've had time to review it better. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Incidentally, for that particular example, we can now use `element.hidden = true` in most situations.

Comment: `hidden` maintains the position and size, so only useful with non-flowing elements like those that are absolute positioned.

Comment: The new HTML5 hidden attribute is exactly equivalent to `display:none` not to be confused with the CSS property `visibility:hidden` which behaves how you describe.