# How to make a progress bar increase in size by increasing the width but without any inline style so it doesn't upset CSP

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy

It seems fairly straight forward, there's a few options I'm thinking of but W3 says to use inline style. It's weird that a resource as trusted as W3 would tell people to do something that is not standardised and a security issue. I wondered if a pro could tell me the the official stance on this subject. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp see they have used inline style for the width. It's what I have currently implemented but want to change.

WC3 explains it really simple, its very easy to implement. Simply increase the width inline style inside a javascript loop and you have a basic progress bar. But, The thing is that inline style is a hotspot for XSS attacks and so because I'm using CSP I've eliminated all inline style and script, except my progress bars. I'm a little stuck as how the best method to do this is.

Interestingly, inline style which is added from a safe script is allowed and doesn't upset CSP, however, in any documentation i have found about this subject, 99 times out of 100 it will say clearly that inline style is a security risk, of course it also depends on other factors but to be inline with best practice and safety, I've opted to remove everything even that which is done on the live dom.

So how could I increase the width inside a loop without using inline style?

This Link [Content Security Policy vs variable inline style (CSP vs CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632373/content-security-policy-vs-variable-inline-style-csp-vs-css) suggests that its ok to use inline style on the live Dom, as suggested in other articles. You can't use el.setAttribute but you can use el.style. It also says that when CSP level 3 is more widely adopted this wont be ok. Which I'm not sure if its right or not, I'm pretty sure chrome latest has CSP3 and I'm testing in that and the style I'm using is still accepted. I don't really see any definite answer on this. @Thomas what do you take from that link? This is the comment that I keep finding dotted around the internet in different ways. "That's still an inline style, regardless of how you represent it. Just because you are getting away with it now doesn't mean that you will when CSP Level 3 is adopted". Is this a red herring or am I understanding right that just because CSP isn't having a paddy now, it will in the future. Or more to the point, it's just an added security risk right? I keep flitting between leaving it and doing something about it, depending on what article I've just read. lol Someone must know the official answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content Security Policy vs variable inline style (CSP vs CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632373/content-security-policy-vs-variable-inline-style-csp-vs-css)

Comment: @Thomas i updated my question because it was too long to leave as a comment please take a look.

Comment: I don't see why forbidding _only_ inline style manipulation from an _already trusted script_ would make things more secure. The script can already modify the entire DOM anyway. So if it were up to me, this would still be allowed in CSP3.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, that's in agreement with [this comment by mikewest](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/212#issuecomment-303829004).

Comment: I think i've been spending too much time swatting flies with this. I ended up removing all the dynamic inline style which was coming from js. I have posted the solution i used below.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments There is no way to do this. It's not possible. Stop wasting your time trying and move on to the next task.

if your still interested then read down, the solution below is not a solution just so you know. skip to the comments.

To put it simply, i've edited the stylesheet rule rather than add inline style.

```js
// this gets the style sheets loaded in the dom as an array
var sheets = document.styleSheets;

//this gets the rules in the form of an array from the first sheet
var rules = sheets[0].cssRules || sheets[0].rules;

// this will be used to mark every iteration of the progress loop.
var i = 0;

// this fires up the function below
progressTimer();


function progressTimer(){
// this sets a timout every 10th of a second 
setTimeout(function(){
      
      // this is used to mark a percentage of progress. In this case because the loop runs every 10th of a second, this will represent 1%
      var newwidth = ++i;
      
      //this is setting the new width of the progress bar inside the style sheet 
      
      // NOTE!!! this is instead of setting element.style.prop = val (which is still allowed from a trusted source but probably will break in the future maybe depending on who knows what.) and definately don't do this element.setAttribute(style, ".somerule{prop:val;}"); as that flag an error from CSP
      
      rules[1].style.width = newwidth+'%';
      
      //this checks if we have reached 100% yet
      if(newwidth < 100){
      // if we have then loop again in a 10th of a second
       progressTimer();
      }else{
      // we are at 100%
      // reset the progress width marker
        i = 0;
        // reset the progress width in the style sheet
        rules[1].style.width = '0%'
        //run it again just for fun
         progressTimer();
      }
    
},100);
}
```

```css
.barouter{ 
  border:solid grey thick;
  width:100%;
}

.barinner{ 
  height:20px;
  background:yellow;
  width:0px;
  
  -transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear; 
}
```

```html
<div class="barouter">
  <div class="barinner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I actually spent about 20 minutes writing this here, i wont bother again lol. The answer is a simple as the question. Edit the style sheet rule rather than add inline style to the element.

Comment: The security threat is not in the built-in styles, but in the ability of an attacker to inject them, because it make possible  UI redress attack. Your solution to a "non-existent problem" does not add any security because `rules[1].style.width = newwidth+'%';` has the same "security" as `element.style.width = newwidth+'%';`.  In result you do not get any additional safety.

Comment: So the answer should be that there is no way to do it. I cant think of any other way to manipulate the style. @granty

Comment: Manipulating the style by JS (like `el.style.width = value` or `el.style.backgrpundColor = '#e2e2e2'`) is absolutely safe from the CSP point of view. Your "decision" has the right to life, it just does not bring additional security (it does not add a protection against any threats).